# What are the first things I should do to convert my Codeigniter PHP web app to an iOS app?

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter

I have a PHP-coded website working on a codeigniter framework.  I want to create the iOS app version of this and understand they are completely different. But I want to learn while I try to make the app happen.

I have spring break next week and want to try and get really far. I need to connect my site to a MySQL database and run a bunch of different algorithms.  I am assuming I will need to re-write all of the algorithms into a new language (Objective-C I believe) I just want to know the best way to get started building the app. I want to make sure I'm watching tutorials that will be beneficial to my end goals, rather just learn the basic core.

I have things like xcode set up, just need to know where I should go.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you really want to make a native app than you have to rewrite all in Objective-C.
You also need an API on your server to connect to MySql from external device.

This API is usally REST or SOAP based. If you need to deal with user login than OAuth is the way to go.

But there are alternatives to native apps. One interesting thing is a hybrid app. This is a native browser element and inside that browser your normal website with a mobile optimized layout is running. With a hybrid app you can get into app store, too. Look at http://phonegap.com/.

Another solution is to only make a mobile optimized or responsive layout for your site. If you don't need to be in app store or don't need native functions like GPS, accelerometer etc. than this is a good option.

Comment: oh wow! If an hybrid app can get in the app store and just run a mobile optimized layout, that's what I'm looking for.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think with apple is not so easy to get into app store. You have to create the look and feel of an ios gui. Look at [http://jquerymobile.com/](http://jquerymobile.com/) this can help you with that..

Comment: @DanielFein If this pointing you to simply use a layout optimized for mobile, you could skip phonegap and simply create a web app (and skip the app stores). But first, define your needs, and based on that, decide if you want to use Phonegap, or fully native solution.

Comment: I have a web app but feel that an app store is something that would let the idea run to a new market and expand.  Plus I feel the product is something that would operate well as an app.  I know people can just go to the mobile site, but there's a different feel for this that would operate well under a native app.